# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: al intentar instalar las librerías "flask_mysqldb y flask_bcrypt" en vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pip

Uso el comando: `pip install flask_mysqldb` para intentar instalar `flask_mysqldb` y me produce el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La instalación comienza bien, pero no sé por que después me marca error.

Tengo instalado Python 3.9.0 (64-bit) en windows 10 **también me marca un error parecido** con el comando: `pip install flask_bcrypt`

Es un proyecto de creación de la base de datos, y necesito esas librerías para poder capturar los datos del usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te está surgiendo por culpa de la versión de Python.

Podemos ver en [su documentación](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) y también en [su Github](https://github.com/alexferl/flask-mysqldb), que `flask_mysqldb` **Solo tiene soportado y testeado hasta Python 3.7** por lo que no aseguran que funcione en versiones superiores.

Para poder instalarlo necesitas instalar **una versión de Python que sea menor o igual a Python 3.7**.

### Consejo

La versión de Python 3.9 salió a principios de octubre de 2020. Normalmente (salvo que tengas algún motivo), es bueno esperar a que pasen algunos meses, o incluyo un año, para instalar las últimas versiones de Python, ya que al ser todas las librerías **open software** no es una empresa que todo este organizado, y **tardan un tiempo en actualizarse** a las versiones correspondientes.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, sí era ese el problema que tenía y gracias también por ese consejo.